# Find "’" and other interesting characters

Tags: html, visual-studio

When inserting copy into an HTML document I get from sources such as word documents or PDFs I'd like to make sure that the special quotes and apostrophes get replaced with their generic counterparts.

In other words, I'd like to replace things like `’` with `'` and then `“` and `”` with `"`.

Is there maybe some kind of add on for visual studio that would do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visual Studio's regular-expression-based find/replace can search and replace Unicode characters, among which you can count the "smart quote" characters.

For example, if I find `\u2018` and `\u2019` and replace with `'`, that gets rid of the "smart" single quotes.

For the relevant Unicode character codes, you can check [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotation_mark_glyphs) or surely many other places.

Comment: I found this page where someone created a macro to quickly perform search and replace tasks: http://www.helixoft.com/blog/archives/15